# I need with this code I have a sorting issue I cant figure out

Tags: python-3.x

```
movieDict = {"Munich":[2005, "Steven Spielberg"],
                        "The Prestige": [2006, "Christopher Nolan"],
                        "The Departed": [2006, "Martin Scorsese"],
                        "Into the Wild": [2007, "Sean Penn"],
                        "The Dark Knight": [2008, "Christopher Nolan"],
                        "Mary and Max": [2009, "Adam Elliot"],
                        "The King\'s Speech": [2010, "Tom Hooper"],
                        "The Artist": [2011, "Michel Hazanavicius"],
                        "The Help": [2011, "Tate Taylor"],
                        "Argo": [2012, "Ben Affleck"],
                        "12 Years a Slave": [2013, "Steve McQueen"],
                        "Birdman": [2014, "Alejandro G. Inarritu"],
                        "Spotlight": [2015, "Tom McCarthy"],
                        "The BFG": [2016, "Steven Spielberg"]}
promptForYear = True
while promptForYear:
    yearChoice = int(input("Enter a year between 2005 and 2016:\n"))
    if yearChoice<2005 or yearChoice>2016:
        print("N/A")   
    else:
        for key, value in movieDict.items():
            if value[0] == yearChoice:
                print(key + ", " + str(value[1]) )
        promptForYear = False          
menu = "MENU" \
        "\nSort by:" \
        "\ny - Year" \
        "\nd - Director" \
        "\nt - Movie title" \
        "\nq - Quit\n"
promptUser = True
first_time = True
while promptUser:
    if first_time == True:
        print()
        first_time = False
    print(menu)
    userChoice = input("Choose an option:\n")
    if userChoice == "q":
        promptUser = False
    elif userChoice=="y":
        year_sorted = {}            
        for key, value in sorted(movieDict.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
            year = value[0]
            title = key
            director = value[1]
            if year not in year_sorted:
                year_sorted[year] = [[title, director]]
            else:
                year_sorted[year].append([title, director])            
        for year in sorted(year_sorted):
            print (year,end=':\n')
            movies = year_sorted[year]
            for movie in sorted(movies, key = lambda x:x[0]):
                print("\t"+movie[0] + ", " + movie[1])
            print()
    elif userChoice == "d":
        director_sorted = {}
        for key, value in sorted(movieDict.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1][1])):
            year = value[0]
            title = key
            director = value[1]
            if director not in director_sorted:
                director_sorted[director] = [[title, year]]
            else:
                director_sorted[director].append([title, year])            
        for director in sorted(director_sorted):
            print (director,end=':\n')
            movies = director_sorted[director]
            for movie in sorted(movies, key = lambda x:x[0]):
                print("\t"+movie[0] + ", " + str(movie[1]))            
            print()
    elif userChoice == "t":
        for key, value in sorted(movieDict.items(), key=lambda item: (item[0], item[1])):
            print(key,end=':\n')
            print("\t" + str(value[1]) + ", " + str(value[0])+"\n")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

I need help figuring out why when I enter:

```
2014
y
q
```

under 2006 the movies are sorted like so:

```
2006:
    The Departed, Martin Scorsese
    The Prestige, Christopher Nolan
```

but I need them to print out like:

```
2006:
    The Prestige, Christopher Nolan
    The Departed, Martin Scorsese
```

Also when I enter:

```
2008
d
q
```

It prints:

```
Christopher Nolan:
    The Dark Knight, 2008
    The Prestige, 2006
```

but I need it to print:

```
Christopher Nolan:
    The Prestige, 2006
    The Dark Knight, 2008
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a **minimal** [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code segment here:

```
movies = year_sorted[year]
for movie in sorted(movies, key = lambda x:x[0]):
  print("\t"+movie[0] + ", " + movie[1])
```

forces your year sorting to come out as it is. You're telling it to sort movies alphabetically which is exactly what it's doing. You have the same thing going on when you sort by directors. So if you want your movies to sort the inverse of that, you're going to need to tell it to do so

```
movies = year_sorted[year]
for movie in sorted(movies, key = lambda x:x[0], reverse=True):
  print("\t"+movie[0] + ", " + movie[1])
```

You might also be intending to sort by the director/year instead of the title in which case you need to change your lambda to `lambda x:x[1]` so that it sorts by the second object in the list instead of the first.

Comment: @JoshuaMcnew No problem. Might want to be a bit more clear what your code is trying to do in future questions though. I wasn't exactly sure what your end-goal of the sorting process was so figuring out what was wrong took a bit longer then usual xD

Comment: Will do I wasn't exactly sure how to explain it but i'll work on it! Cheers